# Where can I find my test release on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, alpha, google-play-console

I have an Alpha release for my game but I can't find where to download and test it.

[image]

I go to my test URL play.google.com/apps/testing/my.app.name and it says I am a tester...

[image]

But it says 'item not found' in the app store.
Here is a screenshot of the Alpha test. I find Google Play very unintuitive and can't tell if the test is actually 'live'

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had not hit "Publish" in the Pricing and Distribution area.